# Como obter a língua do browser em um ServiceWorker?

Tags: web-worker

Como obter a língua do browser em um ServiceWorker?

```
navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; //não funciona
```

Comment: O que ele esta retornando no navigator.language ?

Comment: undefined. service worker é outro contexto.

Comment: Sim, apesar disso eu achava que ele tinha o language uma vez que eu lembrava que ele tem o userAgent. Cara, acho que vale a pena você definir uma função de comunicação com o front e fazer o sw cachear a resposta.

Comment: Por que você precisa dessa informação no sw?